# Deleting all references to a framework manually in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode

I forgot to click "Delete all references" when I deleted a framework in Xcode 5. Now I would like to delete them all manually but Xocde is still stating that "name.framework" is still inside my Application. How can I delete all references entirely so I can add a framework with the same name as the one I previously deleted?

Comment: What is the exact error message that Xcode is displaying? One place to check is in the target settings, under the Build Settings in Framework Search Paths. But without the error message, it's hard to know what to suggest.

Comment: The error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I tried dragging in the framework under a different name, then renamed it to what I want it to be named (so as to sync with everything that is already inside Xcode) inside Xocode, this seemed to work, but it is still giving me the error I just mentioned.

Comment: My framework search paths are standard for where my app is located, one for debug and one for release. Then the debug and release in the subdirectories look like this: *.nib *.lproj*.framwork *.gch *.xcode*(*).DS_Store CVS.svn .git.hg, which may be referring to another framework. The framework I am trying to use is the Dropbox.framwork.